# Java Main Method Magic Numbers

Tags: java, checkstyle, magic-numbers

So im trying to get rid of two magic numbers that i have in my main method. I tried making them static fields but i just get a different checkstyle error. I'm looking for a way to make my main method check out completely with checkstyle.

These are the checkstyle errors i get:

> '2000' is a magic number
>
> '262' is a magic number

These are the checkstyle errors when i make them static fields:

> Name 'twothou' must match pattern '^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*(_[A-Z0-9]+)*$'.
>
> Name 'twosixtytwo' must match pattern '^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*(_[A-Z0-9]+)*$'.

P.S. if i try to make the variables non static it wont let me compile.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you add the relevant part of your code so we can see what you're trying to do?

Comment: Oops, sorry. Thanks for the help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad

Answer (score 5):

The "Magic Number" warnings are telling you that you should [use a numeric constant instead of a hard-coded number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad) in your code.

The other errors just mean that you should use [standard naming practices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java) for your identifiers.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need only change your field variable names to all CAPS.

Try TWO_THOU and TWO_SIXTY_TWO.

Comment: AH i think that might be the problem i will go try it right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the value in final int variable then use it probably then you avoid the checkstyle issue.

int hashcode=hashcode+4; // checkstyle violation since 4 is a magic number

final int value=4;
int hashcode=hashcode+value; // no violation

Comment: If you want to format your code, check out https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for Markdown stylings :)